Does Colossians 1:16 say that Jesus created the heaven and the earth?
Colossians 1:16 ASV
for in him were all things created, in the heavens and upon the earth, things visible and things invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or powers; all things have been created through him, and unto him;

No. The antecedent in verse 13 is 'his dear Son' the 'his' referring to the Father. It is important to get the context correct in regard to names and titles.

Colossians 1:16 ESV - For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him.

Short Answer: Jesus played an essential and active role in the creation process.
Definition: Creator - a person or thing that brings something into existence. (Oxford Languages)
Scriptural consistency:
John 1:3 states, "All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.”
Hebrews 1:2 says, “but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son, whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created the world.”
The Greek uses the phrase “ἐν αὐτῷ ἐκτίσθη τὰ πάντα” (en autō ektisthē ta panta), translated as “in him all things were created.”
The word “ἐκτίσθη” (ektisthē) is a form of the verb “κτίζω” (ktizō), which means "to build, create." So, we would say that Jesus is the agent of creation.

Notice too that the verse also mentions that all things were created “for him.” Thus, Jesus is not only the agent of creation but also the purpose for which creation exists.
An agent is someone who acts on behalf of another or carries out a task. In this context, Jesus is the agent of creation because all things were created "through him."

Absolutely yes and without a doubt. Read the context starting at vs15, "And He/Jesus Christ is the image of the invisible God, the first-born of all creation."
Vs16, FOR (or because of what was said at vs15) by Him all things were created, in the heavens and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities--all things have been, (past tense) created by Him and for Him."
So what was your question again? "Does Colossians 1:16 say that Jesus created the heaven and the earth?" Does not vs16 make it perfectly clear, "by Him all things were created, in the heavens and on earth." So what is your objection regarding the text/context?
If you want to make an issue out the little words, "by" or "through" I will give you their definitions. "By" means, "by the agency of, origin, a result. Through, is used to indicate, "The manner in which something is achieved."
Maybe I should share with you something I learned decades ago regarding "words." Something cannot mean something other than what it says, and what it says is based in the words, their definitions, grammar, and syntax. I don't care whether it is literal, figurative, metaphorical, poetic. Something cannot mean something other than what it says.
Now, if you doubt me why don't you show me your exegesis of the verses I quoted in a way that demonstrates how you can deny the obvious of what it says?

+1. Many thanks.

I know where you are leading us to. Nevertheless, here is my sincere and honest answer:
Answer
Colossians 1:16 does not say that Jesus Christ created the heavens and the earth.
But then, neither does Colossians 1:16 say that God the Father created the heavens and the earth!!
So, the truth is that Colossians does not say who created the heavens and the earth. It simply says Jesus created all things, both visible and invisible in heaven and on earth.
Then, who created the heavens and the earth, in the first place?
Explanation
We need other verses to see who created the heavens and the earth.
Lord Jesus Christ says:

“My Father, Lord of heaven and earth” (Mat 11:25).

But the interesting thing is that God the Father Himself says it is Jesus Christ as Yahweh who created the heavens and the earth:

“but as to the Son, "Your throne, O God…….And, "You,
Lord (Yahweh), at the beginning founded the earth, and the heavens are works of Your hands. They will vanish away, but You will
continue; and they will all become old, like a garment, and You shall
fold them up like a covering, and they shall be changed. But You are
the same, and Your years shall not fail" (Heb 1:8,10-12).

So, we see that God the Father Himself-

Calls Jesus God;
Calls Jesus Yahweh; and
Says Jesus created the heavens and the earth.

This is the truth proclaimed by God the Father Himself and every true Christian is bound to believe this true witness as otherwise he is making God the Father into a liar which will be a grievous error to make; so says Apostle John:

“the witness of God is greater; because this is the witness of God
which He has witnessed about His Son: … The one not believing God has
made Him a liar, because he has not believed in the witness which God
has witnessed concerning His Son” (1 John 5:9,10).

So, men say God the Father created the heavens and the earth which is not wrong as ultimately God is the Creator.
But, God the Father Himself says Lord Jesus Christ created the heavens and the earth. This means Jesus Christ, the monogenes Son is the Creator just as His Father is the Creator.
Like Father like Son.

“All things came into being through Him, and without Him not even
one thing came into being that has come into being” (John 1:3).

(Such an emphatic statement!)
Through/By
When the Scripture shows that God the Father created everything through (Greek “dia”) Jesus Christ, it does not mean that God the Father used Jesus as a “magic wand” and created things. No.
It simply means Jesus Christ created everything on behalf of God the Father.
An Example from Scripture:-
For example, the Scripture says that God will judge men “through” Jesus Christ:

“in the day when God will judge the secrets of men, according to my
good news, through (the same Greek “dia”) Jesus Christ” (Rom
2:16).

How does this happen?

“For the Father judges no one, but has given all judgment to the
Son” (John 5:22).


“Then I solemnly witness before God and the Lord Jesus Christ, He
being about to judge the living and dead at His appearance and His
kingdom” (2 Tim 4:1).

Now we learn that when the Scripture says that God did everything through (Greek “dia”) Jesus, it simply means Jesus actually did everything on behalf of God the Father.
Jesus can do everything for God the Father because He is the Creator just as His Father is the Creator. Like Father like Son.
[Now we know who is sitting on the great White Throne in the White Throne Judgement (Revelation 20:11-12)]
Conclusion
Lord Jesus Christ is God and Creator Just as His Father is God and Creator. We need to honor (worship) Him just as we honor (worship) God the Father (John 5:23).
